# NullPointerException Fetching data from .NET webapi inside Spring Boot (with JWT Security) Rest Service using RestTemplate via Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, resttemplate

.NET WebAPI + MongoDB for products DB
Spring Boot Security (JWT) + MySQL for user acounts DB and auth
I'm trying to fetch price from .NET webAPI inside Spring boot's service

Spring boot ProductService:

```
@Service
public class ProductService {
    public long getProductPrice(String pid) {
        // uri that returns product price (like 9999.99)
        final String uri = "http://localhost:5000/api/products/price?pid="+pid;
        RestTemplate restTempl = new RestTemplate();
        long price = restTempl.getForObject(uri, long.class);
        System.out.println(price); // here it prints null
        return price;
    }
}
```

.NET WebAPI Controller:

```
[HttpGet("price")]
public decimal GetProductPrice([FromQuery] string pid){
    return _productService.GetProductPrice(pid);
}
```

everything works fine even "BUILD SUCCESS". But whenever getProductPrice (provided pid) is called it prints and returns null with NullPointerException on console.

UPDATE:
I temporarily switched to a simple PHP Rest API and called uri. This time everything works fine and fetched and printed the price without giving any exception on Spring boot side.
I've noticed that when i use uri **http**://... in web browser it auto redirects to **https**://... with NOT SECURE TAG on address bar. Is that's the main reason? is there any SSL configurations that needs to be done on Spring Boot Service Side? or there is any other issue with my code. Please help.

Comment: Uri correct? Products app running? Any errors on the products app side? Valid response returned by the products app?

Comment: @Serge uri returns product price from mongodb. Tested on postman and chrome also. It's a GET request

Answer (score 0):

In the product app, do you see any incoming request sent by getProductPrice()? Something in the access logs may be? If yes, what is the response status? If not, why was there no request sent by getProductPrice()? In this case there must be an error on the sender side.